# Is it already possible to test Ubuntu for Android?

Tags: testing, ubuntu-for-android

I'm very excited about Ubuntu being able to run trhough an Android smartphone just by connecting it to a monitor, a keyboard and a mouse. Now I'm wondering if there is a way to test it? Are there any daily-builds of it? Alpha package?

If you don't know what Ubuntu for Android is [take a look at it's page](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android).

Other things I'm unsure about Ubuntu for Android is:

- Will it work for tablets too?
- Does it require a dual-core smartphone?
- Do you necessarily need a Dock?
- Is there a release date for the first version of it?

I've looked for some info in Ubuntu for [Android LaunchPad page](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-for-android), but I didn't find anything useful.

In [This Page](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android/contact-us) Canonical lets you to leave your contact if you are interest in Ubuntu for Android.

Comment: Ubuntu is about to anounce a new product (we don't know what yet; see [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/) for the countdown). It could very well be Ubuntu for Android. So just hold tight and you might be able to try it out in less than two days.

Comment: I would like if it is Ubuntu for Android, but I would love if it is a entirely new product, I always love new things ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently, it is for OEMs to install on their devices, not for the consumer. 
When it is released, it shall be hacked on to these old devices.

Comment: What a petty, I was hopping there existed a way do get Ubuntu for Android, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

The only supported device at the moment is the Nexus 7 tablet, no smartphone.

Install instructions:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation

More info:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/ubuntu-installer-for-nexus-7-tablet-made-available-for-devs
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1957561

Comment: This is not the Ubuntu for Android he meant.

Comment: Totally different thing.